# Check if all List Items have the same member value in C#

Tags: c#

I'm searching for a simple and fast way to check if all my Listitems have the same value for a member.

```
foreach (Item item in MyList)
{
    Item.MyMember = <like all other>;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I forgot one thing: If one of this members (its a string) is String.Empty and all other items have the same string it should be true too! Sorry i forgot this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, after the new requirement has

```
bool allSame = !MyList.Select(item => item.MyMember)
                      .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                      .Distinct()
                      .Skip(1)
                      .Any();
```

That avoids you having to take a first step of finding *one* sample value to start with. (And it will still exit as soon as it finds the second value, of course.)

It *also* only iterates over the sequence once, which may be important if it's not really a repeatable sequence. Not a problem if it's a `List<T>` of course.

EDIT: To allay concerns over `Skip`, from the documentation:

> If *source* contains fewer than *count* elements, an empty `IEnumerable<T>` is returned. If *count* is less than or equal to zero, all elements of *source* are yielded.

Comment: Clever, but I think the Skip(1) will throw if MyList is empty.

Comment: How can i use the methode `.Select`?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: I check the List if it is empty before i use it.

Comment: @Jon Doesn't your logic return notAllSame rather than allSame?

Comment: @Henk: No it won't. Trust me :)

Comment: @XmlmXmlmX: You need a `using` directive for `System.Linq`, and a reference to `System.Core`. And you need to be on .NET 3.5 or higher, of course. And you won't need to check whether or not the list is empty before running this code - so long as it's not a null reference, this is fine.

Comment: I forgot one thing: If one of this members (its a string) is String.Empty and all other items have the same string it should be true too! Sorry i forgot this.

Comment: @XmlmXmlmX: It's not clear to me what you mean... is that regardless of the first member? If you could give some concrete examples, that would really help... I'll pre-emptively edit anyway...

Comment: Ok, MyList have 4 Items. One item member is empty, the other one are same. The empty member is like a same member.

Comment: Then you just need to add Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) between Select and Distinct       (this does consider string.Empty and null strings as 'wildcards', if you want to consider Empty strings only: Where(item => (item != string.Empty) )

Comment: @XmlmXmlmX: BTW can they all be string.Empty?

Comment: @XmlmXmlmX: actually it does not matter, Jon's logic will work equally

Comment: @XmlmXmlmX: It doesn't matter - it's just the lambda expression parameter. You can change it to `item` if you want.

Comment: @JonSkeet why not just `bool allSame = MyList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.MyMember)).All(item => item.MyMember == MyList.First().MyMember);`? For my case, `!jobs.All(x => x.JobId == jobs.First().JobId)` because I don't have the empty string requirement. Is there something wrong with this very simple approach?

Comment: @JamesHurley: I'm afraid I don't have time to get my head back into what I was thinking 11 years ago and compare it with your solution. If it works for you and you prefer it, that's fine. (Note that my solution does only access the sequence once though - your approach calls `First()` many times. May well not be a problem for you, e.g. if it's for a list, but for other sequences it could be an issue.)

Answer (score 9):

Your own solution is simple enough already, but if you wanted to abstract away the loop and write it more expressively, you could use Linq.

```
bool allSame = MyList.All(item => item.MyMember == someValue);
```

Comment: That assumes you already know the value you're looking for, of course.

Comment: someValue is not known beforehand. The OP's own solution is schematic.

Comment: All true, if you don't have the value beforehand and it might be expensive to get it, I too might go for Jon's solution.

Comment: Why not just look at the first one? It gets a little more complicated because empty strings are ignored but does it really matter what the value is? If they all need to be the same we can just assume the first one is the correct value and if any don't match then we are done. If they all match then every one of them is equal

Answer (score 6):

```
using System.Linq;
…

if (myList.Any()) // we need to distinguish between empty and non-empty lists 
{
    var value = myList.First().MyMember;
    return myList.All(item => item.MyMember == value);
}
else
{
    return true;  // or false, if that is more appropriate for an empty list    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic one that works for all version of .NET beginning with 2.0:

```
public static bool AllSameByProperty<TItem, TProperty>(IEnumerable<TItem> items, Converter<TItem, TProperty> converter)
{
    TProperty value = default(TProperty);
    bool first = true;

    foreach (TItem item in items)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            value = converter.Invoke(item);
            first = false;
            continue;
        }

        TProperty newValue = converter.Invoke(item); 

        if(value == null)
        {
            if(newValue != null)
            {
                return false;
            } 

            continue;
        }

        if (!value.Equals(newValue))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Its usage in C# 2.0:

```
AllSameByProperty(list, delegate(MyType t) { return t.MyProperty; });
```

Its usage in C# 3.0:

```
AllSameByProperty(list, t => t.MyProperty);
```

Comment: What if the first member has "null" as the value and the second has a non-null value? That will give a false positive.

Answer (score -1):

Iam doing like so:

```
Item item = MyList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.MyMember != valueToMatch);
bool allMembersSame = item == null;
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this is the shortest and most elegant solution:

```
bool allSame = list.GroupBy(item => item.TheProperty).Count == 1;
```