# Code Contract that Ensures that All Items in a Collection are the Same

Tags: code-contracts

How can I create a post-condition that ensures that all items in a collection are the same?

I was thinking of using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956096/check-if-all-list-items-have-the-same-member-value-in-c-sharp/6956136#6956136) but I'm unsure whether that might cause some unwanted side-effects or if it would be a wrong use of code contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked code appears to be side-effect free, so I wouldn't worry about that. I recommend putting the code that checks the all-equal condition into its own (pure) function, and simply calling that.

```
Contract.Ensures(AllEqual(myEnumeration));
```

This means that AllEqual need to be at least as visible as your method itself, but I think it will make everything cleaner.