# Determine if all elements of a List are true or false

Tags: c#, linq, list, boolean

i have to chek if all elements of a `List<bool>` are `true` or all elements are `false`

```
List<bool> b1 = new List<bool>() { true, true, true, true }; //valid
List<bool> b2 = new List<bool>() { false, false, false, false }; //valid
List<bool> b3 = new List<bool>() { true, false, false, true }; //not valid
```

Is there a Linq approach instead of my current loop?

```
bool isValid = true;
for (int i = 1; i < b3.Count; i++)
{
    if (b3[i] != b3[i - 1])
        isValid = false;
}
```

Comment: You mean the LINQ `All()` extension method...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307172/check-if-all-items-are-the-same-in-a-list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681351/c-sharp-check-if-all-strings-in-list-are-the-same, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956096/check-if-all-list-items-have-the-same-member-value-in-c-sharp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390406/using-linq-or-otherwise-how-do-check-if-all-list-items-have-the-same-value-and

Comment: Would this be faster than `All`: `var isAllTrue = !b3.Any(x => !x);`

Comment: Enumerable.Range(0, b3.Length - 1).All(i => b3[i] == b3[i+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool result = myList.All(a => a) || myList.All(a => !a);
```

This should work