# Testing if a certain field in a object is empty (for all items in the list)

Tags: c#

I have a variable defined like this:

```
List<Item> _Treasures;
```

The object `Item` it declared like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name
    {
        get => _Name; set => _Name = value;
    }
    private string _Name;

    public string Theme
    {
        get => _Theme; set => _Theme = value;
    }
    private string _Theme;

    public string Method
    {
        get => _Method; set => _Method = value;
    }
    private string _Method;

    public int Time
    {
        get => _Time; set => _Time = value;
    }
    private int _Time;

    public Item()
    {
        _Name = "";
        _Theme = "";
        _Method = "";
        _Time = 0;
    }
}
```

I am trying to find the simplest way in code to test if all `Item.Name` values in the list are empty. I know I can use a `foreach` loop on the list and text each `Name` field and maintain a `bool` flag to indicate when one of the names is not empty and break the loop.

But can I achieve this with some other simplified test?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all List Items have the same member value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956096/check-if-all-list-items-have-the-same-member-value-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) is perfect for this:

```cs
bool allNamesEmpty = _Treasures.All(t => t.Name == string.Empty);
```

Side note; all of those properties can be rewritten as (simpler) auto-properties with initializers:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Theme { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Method { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Time { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Comment: Auto properties. Does that still apply when the object is serializable to xml?